# phonegap local notification from dreawmweaver html5

Tags: html, localnotification, phonegap-pushplugin

Can someone help me with phonegap local notification, I'm trying to implement this with my phonegap htlm5 app and i can't find any examples or tutorials for it? and how to install the plugin in config.xml file as well.

Thank you

Comment: Did you see [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)?

Comment: here where? I did but could not find it though.